# How to use nAngular2 DynamicComponentLoader with @ViewChild

Tags: angular

I'm using the `DynamicComponentLoader` to load a component dynamically, which is passed by a parameter. I'd like to use the old `loadIntoLocation` method, but that has been removed as of beta16 (I'm using RC0).

In the end I would like to be able to load a component inside the `#activeComponent` div while still being able to toggle a parents visibility, like so:

```
<div *ngIf="isOpen>
  <div #activeComponent></div>
</div>
```

This is what I got:

```
@Input() activeComponent: any;
constructor(){}
ngOnChanges() {
  this._dynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation(this.activeComponent, this._viewContainerRef);
}
```

And this works, but, as the method's name implies, the component is loaded **next** to location, as a sibling. I would like a **child**, like the old `loadIntoLocation` method.

The Angular 2 beta16 changelog writes: *Use @ViewChild(‘myVar’, read: ViewContainerRef) to get hold of a ViewContainerRef at an element with variable myVar. Then call DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation.*

This is what I would like to work:

```
@ViewChild('activeComponent',) child: ViewContainerRef;
constructor(){}
ngOnChanges() {
    if (!this.activeComponent) return;
    this._dynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation(this.activeComponent, this.child);

}
```

But I'm getting : `TypeError: location.createComponent is not a function`.

Anyone who got the `_dynamicComponentLoader` with `@ViewChild` working?

Comment: Do not miss this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37044960/1679310

Answer (score 4):

Similar question here: [Adding new Component element to DOM in Angular 2 at runtime doesn't render the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343195/adding-new-component-element-to-dom-in-angular-2-at-runtime-doesnt-render-the-c/37343364#37343364)

And here's the link for the plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tizrf1Nu9pu7gQc8cVTR?p=preview)

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<button (click)="addCmp()" #activeComponent>add</button>
      <hero-list></hero-list>
      <sales-tax></sales-tax>
      `,
      directives: [HeroListComponent, SalesTaxComponent]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      @ViewChild('activeComponent',{read: ViewContainerRef}) activeComponent: ViewContainerRef;

      constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, injector: Injector,private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

      addCmp(){
        console.log('adding');
        //change HeroListComponent with the one you want
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(HeroListComponent).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
              this.cmpRef = this.activeComponent.createComponent(factory)
            });
          }
```